# How to provide persistance in Arkit?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit

Firstly I would like to say that I'm really beginner in IOS development and AR technology. I have developed sample projects about AR using Arkit. I have created vitrual 3D object and put the object somewhere in real position. But the life cycle of object is for only one session.

I mean that the object appear one session, When I re-open the application in the same location, as normally Its possition losed. I do not save the position of object. How to provide persistance in Arkit ? I have read some articles about it.

For providing persistance AR experiences, Which steps should I follow ? 
How do I combines AR and location services? 
Does anyone has any idea? Could you help me about it?

If the question is duplicate, I am really sorry.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Restoring an AR Session experience has become very simple in **iOS 12** and `ARKit2`. Apple has provided [World Map Persistence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap/archiving_world_map_data_for_persistence_or_sharing) in ARKit2 that lets you persist almost everything about your AR session. You can save the ARKit world map and restore the mapping data later, even when the app is terminated so that users can return to the previous AR Session when they later re-open the app.

As explained in [Apple Documents](http://An%20ARWorldMap%20object%20contains%20a%20snapshot%20of%20all%20the%20spatial%20mapping%20information%20that%20ARKit%20uses%20to%20locate%20the%20user%E2%80%99s%20device%20in%20real-world%20space.), you can:

> Save a world map when your app becomes inactive, then restore it the
>   next time your app launches in the same physical environment. You can
>   use anchors from the resumed world map to place the same virtual
>   content at the same positions from the saved session.
>
> [ARWorldMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap) conforms to the NSSecureCoding protocol, so you can convert
>   a world map to or from a binary data representation using the
>   [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver) and [NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver) classes.

You convert world map to data and store it in a file, then you can load this file later on the next app launch and convert it back to `ARWorldMap` and set scene view configuration’s initial world map to the loaded world map:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Retrieve the persisted world map, then simply set it in the configuration and run the session:

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.initialWorldMap = worldMap

    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}
```

You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/arkit-persistence/) for a complete working example.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. Is it possible that the world map data include more than one virtual content? I mean two objects which postion's are nearly.

Comment: @OfficalMesut World map contains all the objects you have added to the scene, including their positions. They all will restore as they were added in the first place.

Comment: Thank you again. I will try out it . Maybe It was weird question. I try to learn how does work it.